# ng-repeat and compound filter in 1.3.6

Tags: angularjs, filter, upgrade, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've only started learning angular. I decided to upgrade my 1.2 examples to the current version. I spotted that filter doesn't work anymore. It broke in 1.3.6.
I'm no longer able to filter by 2 fields of collection objects.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mpo5UDvzjUWIToTZo142?p=preview

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{age:a,name:q }">
```

How to get this behaviour back? Ultimately I want ng-repeat to display custom directives enclosing content of each friend. 
Will the filter work when I reformat my code?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly working. You should simply not forget to initialize the variables used in the filter predicate, since they are supposed to be strings, [according to the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
// In the controller
$scope.a = '';
$scope.q = '';
```

As a side note, please use more meaningful names for your variables.

Comment: You are spot on! Initialising the query fields solved the problem. I copied the documentation example with the meaningful q parameter ;-) and added my a. Thank you for saving me hours of studying the docs